# Does template declaration order matter in c++

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

The following code is taken from http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std; 

template<class T> // (a) a base template 
void f( T ){
  cout << "base1\n";   
}

template<class T> // (b) a second base template, overloads (a) 
void f( T* ){
  cout << "base2\n";   
}

template<>        // (c) explicit specialization of (b) 
void f(int*){
  cout << "base3\n";   
}

int main()
{
  int *p = NULL; 
  f( p ); 
}
```

The output in the above case is "base3". But if I write (c) above (b), the output is "base2". I tested the above code at cpp.sh. Can anyone please tell me the reason?

Comment: Compare also to the case where `(c)` is an ordinary overload, not a specialization at all: `void f(int*);`.  Then order doesn't matter.

Comment: I had the same question when reading that article. He doesn't explicitly say that it's the order that matters. He simply says "put in this form." I reread it several times to make sure that was the only difference, then came here to make sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the order matters here. If you move (c) before (b), then it becomes an explicit specialization of (a) instead of (b).

In overload resolution between the two primary templates, i.e. (a) and (b), (b) is always selected; but (c) is not the specialization of (b) again and then won't be invoked, so you'll get the output "base2".

Comment: Now the question is how do you specialize (a) when (c) is already declared?

Comment: @Mehrdad Sorry can't get what you mean. How to specialize (a) when (c) is already declared as the specializaiton of (a)?

Comment: @songyuanyao: my bad, I meant how do you specialize (a) for something like `int*` when (b) is already declared after (a)?

Comment: @Mehrdad I see, and I think it's impossible; (b) is more special than (a) for (c), then (c) will always be regarded as the speicialization of (b).